# Finite subset of $V_\omega$ is an element of $V_\omega$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, set-theory

Let $V_\alpha$ be the members of the von Neumann Hierarchy: $$V_0 = \emptyset, V_{\alpha + 1 } = \mathcal{P} (V_\alpha), V_\lambda = \bigcup_{\alpha < \lambda} V_\alpha.$$

I'm reading the proof of [Lemma 2.5.2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzPFI.png) , and I don't understand why in the definition of $f$ ("let $f(a)$ be the least $n$ such that $a\in V_{n+1}$") the author is considering $V_{n+1} $ as opposed to $V_n$.

Under this definition each $a\in A$ lies in $V_{f(a)+1}$, right? Then if $f(a) \leq m$ for all $a$, doesn't this mean that all $a$ lie in $V_{m+1}$? I don't get why all $a$ should lie in $V_m$.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right that there's an off-by-one bug in the proof. Doesn't change anything though, right? (Also, on a side note, it's good practice to give a citation of the book you are quoting here.)

Comment: It's lecture notes by an unknown author (or possibly by Douglas Cenzer): https://people.clas.ufl.edu/cenzer/files/notes1020.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, it should be $a∈V_{m+1}$.
$\newcommand{\rank}{\operatorname{rank}}$
$\newcommand{\ord}{\text{Ord}}$

As for the reason that $f$ uses $V_{n+1}$ (apart from the technical details of wanting $\rank(x)$ to be able to be equal to a limit ordinal):

The function $f(x)$, which I will call $\rank(x)$ from now on, can be defined in few different way, one of them is indeed $$\rank_V(x)=\min\{\alpha\in \ord\mid x\in V_{\alpha+1}\}$$
but, perhaps more intuitively, we can also define it as follows:

\begin{align}
\rank_\in(x)=\sup\{\rank(y)+1\mid y\in x\}
\end{align}

Which intuitively states "the rank of a set is greater than the rank of all sets inside of it, but the ranks of the set's inside of it is unbounded in it".

This definition let us use induction in a very natural way (a way called "well-founded induction"), it also gives us a very natural way to define rank for other well-founded relations (by replacing $\in$ with the well founded relation).

---

Also, note that if $\rank(x)$ would have used $x\in V_\alpha$ it would mean that $\rank(\emptyset)=1$, which is weird (remember that in set theory we usually start counting from $0$), and in general $\rank(\alpha)=\alpha+1$ for each ordinal, which is very unnatural.

As well as: when we do induction on rank, we usually split the steps into "$0$, successor, limit" (not always, but a lot of times), and it would be very weird to split it into "$0$, a successor or a limit, a successor of a successor" instead.

Comment: But for the purposes of this proof, we don't need to deal with the rank, do we? I believe the authour could have defined $f$ to be the smallest $n$ such that $x\in V_n$. By the way, do you know where I can read about the equivalence of the two definitions of rank that you gave? The first one actually looks more intuitive to me, and I don't see how the second one is related to it.

Comment: @cereked964 You are correct, for the purpose of this proof you don't need to deal with ranks, but same can be said about any proof: "any proof using rank can be switch to a similar proof using $\operatorname{rank}'(x)=\min\{\alpha\in \operatorname{Ord}\mid x\in V_{\alpha}\}$ instead". But using the rank function is more natural, and getting used to it early is probably better

Comment: @cereked964 in ["Kenneth Kunen - Set theory" second edition](https://isbnsearch.org/isbn/9781848900509) you can see the discussion about the rank function starts at page $50$ (definiton $I.9.13$) (using the second definition I gave) and he proves that it is the same as the first definition at page $55$ (Lemma $I.9.30$)

Comment: @cereked964 I gave Kunen's book because I happen to own it, but I imagine that most set theory books will prove that

Comment: Thank you. I asked, in a way, a follow-up question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4407300/the-relation-between-rank-and-von-neumanns-hierarchy