# The relation between rank and von Neumann's Hierarchy

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

$\newcommand{\rank}{\operatorname{rank}}$
$\newcommand{\ord}{\text{Ord}}$

(This question, in a sense, is a follow up to [ℋolo's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4406996/1037257).)

Let $V_\alpha$ be the members of the von Neumann Hierarchy: $$V_0 = \emptyset, V_{\alpha + 1 } = \mathcal{P} (V_\alpha), V_\lambda = \bigcup_{\alpha < \lambda} V_\alpha.$$

Define $$\rank(x)=\sup\{\rank(y)+1\mid y\in x\}.$$

I'm interested in the implication $\rank(x) < \kappa \implies x\in V_\kappa$ (maybe this is only true for regular cardinals $\kappa$, I'm not sure). I believe it's indirectly proved in Kunen's book, but he uses different definitions and many minor results that are spread over the previous chapters. I was wondering how to prove the mentioned implication given the definitions that I have?

Also I was wondering how the above implication related to the definition  $$\rank_V(x)=\min\{\alpha\in \ord\mid x\in V_{\alpha+1}\}$$
Does the implication that I'm interested in essentially prove the equivalence of the two definitions of rank (or is it rather the opposite -- the equivalence of the definitions can be used to prove the implication I'm interested in)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implication is true for all ordinals, not just regular cardinals. The converse implication holds as well, i.e. $V_\alpha$ is precisely the set of all sets with rank less than $\alpha$. This immediately implies that for any set $x,$ $\operatorname{rank}(x)$ is the least ordinal $\alpha$ such that $x\in V_{\alpha+1}$.

We can prove the equivalence by induction on $\alpha$. Let  $\operatorname{rank}(x)<\alpha.$ If $y\in x$ then since $\operatorname{rank}(y)<\operatorname{rank}(x)$, we have $y\in V_{\operatorname{rank}(x)}$ by the induction hypothesis. Therefore, $x\subseteq V_{\operatorname{rank}(x)}$, and so we have $x\in V_{\operatorname{rank}(x)+1}\subseteq V_\alpha$.

Conversely, let $x\in V_\alpha$. Then, $x\in V_{\beta+1}$ for some $\beta<\alpha.$ So if $y\in x,$ then $y\in V_\beta$, so by the induction hypothesis, $\operatorname{rank}(y)<\beta.$ Therefore, $\operatorname{rank}(y)+1\le \beta$ for all $y\in x,$ so $\operatorname{rank}(x)\le \beta < \alpha.$

Comment: How does it follow that $V_{rank(x)+1}\subseteq V_\alpha$? You must be using the assumption $rank(x) < \alpha$ in this (since I don't see this assumption being used elsewhere), but I'm missing how exactly.

Comment: @cereked964 $\operatorname{rank}(x)+1 \le \alpha$ and $\beta\le \alpha$ implies $V_\beta\subseteq V_\alpha.$ (I'm also using the assumption $\operatorname{rank}(x) < \alpha$ when I apply the induction hypothesis to $\operatorname{rank}(x)$.)

Comment: Sorry, I'm still confused. There isn't any $\beta$ in the second paragraph (which my question is about); if you used $\beta$ in your comment to mean an arbitrary ordinal, I still don't see why $V_{rank(x)+1} \subseteq V_\alpha$ (or even why $V_\beta \subseteq V_\alpha$, and how this is related to $rank(x)+1$). [As for using the assumption $rank(x) < \alpha$ in the induction hypothesis, I don't see it either -- I thought after writing $rank(y) < rank(x)$ you applied the induction hypothesis "$(\forall \alpha \in On)(rank(y) < \alpha \to y\in V_\alpha)$" with $\alpha = rank(x)$.]

Comment: @cereked964 I mean that for any $\beta\le \alpha,$ $V_\beta\subseteq V_\alpha$ (if this isn't obvious, prove it by induction on $\alpha\ge \beta$). And $\operatorname{rank}(x)+ 1\le \alpha,$ so $V_{\operatorname{rank}(x)+1}\subseteq V_\alpha.$ For the second thing, yes, that's exactly the instance, (though would be less confusing to use a variable name other than $\alpha$). But in order to apply the induction hypothesis, the ordinal you apply it to needs to be less than $\alpha$.